# Migration Conventions

Tags: c#, entity-framework, postgresql, migrations, fluent-api

Tenho uma aplicação MVC em DDD que utiliza SQLServer.

Estou procurando levar o banco de dados para PostGresSQL, 
porém ocorre um erro de duplicidade de FK.

Por exemplo, no padrão SqlServer seria gerado:

```
FK_dbo.Adicao_dbo.OrgaoEmissorAtoLegal_ExTarifOrgEmissorAtoLegaLegalId
FK_dbo.Adicao_dbo.OrgaoEmissorAtoLegal_ExTarifOrgEmissorAtoLegalId
```

Porém no PostGresSQL ao gerar a FK ele tenda fazer:

```
FK_dbo.Adicao_dbo.OrgaoEmissorAtoLegal_ExTarifOrgEmissorAtoLega -- ambas iguais
```

É possível aplicar outra regra na geração das FK de forma automatica?

Alguém já fez isso?

Comment: Qual versão do postgresql você está usando?

Comment: Estive lendo a documentação e um identificador pode ter até 63 caracteres. Verifica se não está havendo alguma inclusão de prefixo no nome da fk na geração. (https://til.hashrocket.com/posts/8f87c65a0a-postgresqls-max-identifier-length-is-63-bytes)

Comment: a versão é a 9.6.10.

Comment: Exatamente o indicador vai até 63 caracteres, mas existe uma forma de dizer isso para o migration para que ao gerar as FK aplique esta nova regra?

Answer (score 0):

Segundo a [documentação](https://til.hashrocket.com/posts/8f87c65a0a-postgresqls-max-identifier-length-is-63-bytes), um identificador só pode ter até 63 caracteres.

Precisa usar chave estrangeira com nome menor. Tente usar uma annottation na geração da mesma para diminuir o nome.

Pelo que vi você usa Fluent. Você pode usar uma modelagem alternativa para os casos de usar postgresql ao invés de sql server.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
        modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
            .HasOne(p => p.Blog)
            .WithMany(b => b.Posts)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.BlogId)
            .HasConstraintName("ForeignKey_Post_Blog");
 }
```

Comment: Em relação a aplicar nomes curtos está tranquilo, mas não quero atribuir nomes para cada objeto, preciso que o migration controle isso e aplique a nova regra, se não quando eu renomear um campo que gerar um drop para a FK, tenho que ficar controlando isso com um grupo de devs fica problematico

Comment: Ao meu ver você tem um erro de arquitetura anterior ao problema atual. Os nomes já foram criados longos demais no início de vida da aplicação. Uma mudança na carga da aplicação não seria nenhum bicho de 7 cabeças perante aos erros do passado. Mas é uma ideia. Espero que ajude.